# Managing multiple VSTS Variables

Tags: azure-devops

I need your valuable advice in managing VSTS variable. We have around 40 -50 variables per build /release. Any better way of managing them ?

Our current approach is MSDN suggested one :

[image]

Any inputs/suggestions for managing bulk variables? Thoughts highly appreciated .

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: This is too broad to give a definitive answer. In general, the answer is "source control." Secrets go into a keyvault or some other form of secret-management system so they can be retrieved at deployment time. Non-secret values that are application-specific can be consumed as part of your deployment process in whatever format you choose to use for them (JSON, PowerShell, YAML, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

If the same variables need to be used for different build/release pipelines, I will suggest to manage the amount of the variables by [**variable groups**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=vsts).

You can add all the variables for common usage into a variable group, and link the variable group into different build/release pipelines.

And once the variables in the variable group is updated, and it will applied to the build/release pipelines automatically.